# torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to use pyTorch when developing a RNN and whenever I try to install it I'm getting an error saying torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd32.whl

This is how I tried to install it according to https://pytorch.org/.

I'm using,

Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using anaconda you can install pytorch using

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

as written on the main pytorch [page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).