# ERROR: torch is not a supported wheel on this platform (Linux, non-Conda)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, torch, dji-sdk

I understand there's a similar question asked but that was for a conda environment.
I am running a non-conda environment for python 3.7.10, 3.8.9
i got the wheels file from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Here are the errors after trying with several versions.

```
pip install torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl 
ERROR: torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip install torch-1.0.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
ERROR: torch-1.0.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip install torch-1.7.0+cu92-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl 
ERROR: torch-1.7.0+cu92-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip install torch-1.7.1+cu92-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl 
ERROR: torch-1.7.1+cu92-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip install torch-1.7.1+cpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl 
ERROR: torch-1.7.1+cpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

This is my python version, i have tried with both python 3.7 and 3.8 virtual environments

```
python3
Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr  3 2021, 01:02:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 20 2021, 21:21:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

My system

```
DJI Manifold 2
NVIDIA Jetson TX2
ARMv8 Processor rev 3 (v8l) × 4 ARMv8 Processor rev 0 (v8l) × 2
NVIDIA Tegra X2 (nvgpu)/integrated
64-bit
```

I have CUDA 9 installed based on the output from deviceQuery

```
/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "NVIDIA Tegra X2"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.0 / 9.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.2
  Total amount of global memory:                 7839 MBytes (8219348992 bytes)
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     256 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1301 MHz (1.30 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1600 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            Yes
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            Yes
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 0 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

Output from `nvcc –version`

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Nov_19_03:16:56_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.252
```

Output from “head -n 1 /etc/nv_tegra_release”

```
“head -n 1 /etc/nv_tegra_release
# R28 (release), REVISION: 2.1, GCID: 11272647, BOARD: t186ref, EABI: aarch64, DATE: Thu May 17 07:29:06 UTC 2018
```

Links i have looked at, but didnt work

1. [torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491650/torch-1-1-0-cp37-cp37m-win-amd64-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform?rq=1)
2. [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform?rq=1)
3. https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Comment: Obviously `x86_64`/`AMD64` packages (I.e. 64 bit Intel) are not going to install on an ARM system. You might have to accept that an ARM CUDA build doesn’t exist, unless your SDK vendor or NVIDIA distribute one, and if they don’t, then you might have to cross compile one yourself

Comment: @talonmies hm yes i have to contact dji's support then. Unfortunately this doesnt seem to be a commonly used platform, and they have made modificaitons to the tx2 too. I will try hunting the user manual again to see if i can make any headway. Would be helpful for anyone use running this thingy too

Answer (score 0):

If DJI Manifold 2 runs Linux4Tegra, you would check your L4T version with:

```
head -n 1 /etc/nv_tegra_release
```

and get a wheel suitable for your version from:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-10-now-available/72048

Comment: i got this output after running the command "# R28 (release), REVISION: 2.1, GCID: 11272647, BOARD: t186ref, EABI: aarch64, DATE: Thu May 17 07:29:06 UTC 2018"... From what i understand my embedded computer comes with jetpack 3.3. May i know what is the L4T version referring to ?

Comment: L4T R28.2.1 is from JetPack 3.3 and already quite old. You may check with DJI how much you can upgrade to newer versions. In case you can't, you may read the whole topic from the link above, or try this script
 https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-scripts/blob/master/pytorch_jetson_install.sh
You may get better advice from jetson forum.

Comment: ok i will go check it out ! Thanks for sharing the link for the script.